# Grepping records from log file using custom separator(regex) and matching keywords

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I've a use-case to find records from application log file that contains specific keywords.
I've tried this using `grep` but it uses `\n` as a line separator and hence the logs(with `\n` in the messages) are partially fetched.

A sample application log file(all of them are separate lines,(in other words) with `\n` at the end) :

```
2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
Fetching last name
{LastName : World}
2017-11-22 03:12:23 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Dummy}
Fetching last name
{LastName : Value}
SomeRandomMessage
2017-11-22 03:12:23 LogManager : SomeRandomMessage
Currently processing data {Name: Dummy2}
Fetching last name
SomeRandomMessage
{LastName : Value3}
.
.
.
.
```

I want to use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` as a record separator and then within records, find if it contains `Hello` and `World`(for example).

Expected output :

```
2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
Fetching last name
{LastName : World}
```

What I've tried :

```
grep 'Hello' fileName
>>
2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` as a record separator

You may use this `gnu-awk` command:

```bash
awk -v RS='[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}' '
   /Hello/ && /World/ {printf "%s", RT $0}' file

2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
Fetching last name
{LastName : World}
```

Here `-v RS='[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}'` will set record separator to date-time string and when we match `Hello` and `World` a record is printed after `RT` i.e. record separator text.

---

For non-gnu POSIX awk you can consider this simple `sed | awk` solution:

```bash
sed -E 's/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2} /\n&/' file |
awk -v RS= '/Hello/ && /World/'

2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
Fetching last name
{LastName : World}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but let me just update the post as blank line there is misleading.
The logs don't have any blank line in between.

Comment: Is this limited to specific version of awk? I tried this command on the sample data that I've in question and it prints the whole file and not the section that you added in the answer.

Comment: Yes, it requires GNU awk for multi-char RS as mentioned in the answer - `You may use this gnu-awk command`.

Comment: @SanketMakani: As noted my original solution requires `gnu-awk`. If you non-gnu awk then multi-char RS won't work. I have added a solution for non-gnu awk in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}){2} / {
    prt()
    rec = $0
    next
}
{ rec = rec ORS $0 }
END {
    prt()
}

function prt() {
    if ( (rec ~ /Hello/) && (rec ~ /World/) ) {
        print rec
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
Fetching last name
{LastName : World}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since these are Logs which are dealing with and you mentioned they are in same format, if this is the case then try following code in GNU `awk`. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8OdXm/1) for used regex(`(^|\n)[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} ([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} LogManager : [^{]*{Name: Hello}\nFetching last name\n{LastName : World`) in GNU `awk` code.

```bash
awk -v RS="" '
{while(match($0,/(^|\n)[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} \
([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} LogManager : \
[^{]*{Name: Hello}\nFetching last name\n\
{LastName : World/)){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** - original answer (see edit/revision) made a few assumptions based on OP's sample input; OP has since stated (per comments) that the sample input is not representative of an actual log file ...

Per comments from OP:

- search pattern(s) won't necessarily reside in the 1st (and/or last) line of a log entry
- a log entry may have a variable number of lines
- cannot rely on the string `LastName` being on the last line of the log entry (and at this point I'm going to assume a log entry may not even contain the string `LastName`)

Assumptions:

- a log entry will always start with a date of the format `YYYY-MM-DD` as the first field of the first line of said log entry
- a search pattern will not span multiple lines
- need to support up to 2 search patterns (more could be added with a redesign)

Adding some additional sample data:

```
$ cat fileName
2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
Fetching last name
{LastName : World}
last line for this entry
2017-11-22 03:12:23 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Dummy}
Fetching last name
{LastName : Value}
last line?
nope, this is the last line
2017-11-22 05:17:33 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Dummy2}
Fetching last name
{LastName : Value3}
2017-11-22 12:13:02 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: WhoYaCalinDummy}
Fetching last name
{LastName : WhoMe}
```

One `awk` idea:

```
findme1='Hello'
findme2='World'

awk -v ptn1="${findme1}" -v ptn2="${findme2}" '

function test_and_print() {
    if (log_entry ~ ptn1 && log_entry ~ ptn2)                        # if ptn1/ptn2 show up anywhere in our log entry then ...
       print log_entry                                               # print it to stdout
    log_entry=""                                                     # reset our variable
}

BEGIN           { date_regex="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" }

$1 ~ date_regex { test_and_print() }                                 # new log entry so test the previous entry
                { log_entry= log_entry (log_entry ? RS : "") $0 }    # append current line to current log entry
END             { test_and_print() }                                 # test the last entry
' fileName
```

For `findme1='Hello'; findme2='World'` this generates:

```
2017-11-22 01:43:36 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: Hello}
Fetching last name
{LastName : World}
last line for this entry
```

For `findme1='Hello'; findme2='Bob'` this generates:

```
 # no output
```

For `findme1='WhoMe'; findme2=''` this generates:

```
2017-11-22 12:13:02 LogManager : Currently processing data {Name: WhoYaCalinDummy}
Fetching last name
{LastName : WhoMe}
```

For `findme1='XXXX'; findme2=''` this generates:

```
 # no output
```

Comment: This is a bit tricky. Log records can have variable number of lines as well as the `LastName` could be anywhere in the log record so this won't be helpful.

Comment: If your real log records can have variable numbers of lines then show in the example in your question log records with variable numbers of lines. Give us something truly representative we can  test a potential solution against.

Comment: I encourage you to learn the use of your namesake, Mr. Morton. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Input file here is assumed to be `stack`.  Keyword search is performed with `sed`, although that is personal preference; you may replace that with `grep` if you wish.  I find `grep` a tiny bit less reliable, myself.

The results of all successful keyword searches are sent to `output.`

```
#!/bin/sh -x

cat > ed1 <<EOF
/2017/
ka
/LastName/
kb
a',b'w f1
a',b'd
wq
EOF

next () {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
exit 0
}

main () {
ed -s stack < ed1
test=$(sed -n '/ello/p' f1)
[[ -n "${test}" ]] && echo "${test}" >> output
rm -v ./f1
next
}

next
```